# Find n in Sum a Series

Tags: java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package exercise_4.pkg25;

/**
 *
 * @author 14111985
 */
public class Exercise_425App {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int total = 0;
        int sumOfTotal = 0;
        int n = 0;


        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            total += i;
            sumOfTotal += total;
        }
        System.out.println(sumOfTotal);
    }
}
```

I need to print the value for n in this sum a series question as well as the sum. I found out how to print the sum. But cant figure out how to get n.      1+(1+2)+(1+2+3)+(1+2+3+4)+(1+2+3+4+n)

Comment: Should n not be an input / the condition on the for loop?

Comment: You mean, given a sum value, what is the value of 'n'?

Comment: No n should not be an input. The question is to print the sum and print n.

Comment: I honestly cant see what was so bad with my question. Dunno why i got minus 10 points!

Comment: @user109649 I'd guess because you seem to have copy/pasted a homework assignment, not clearly stated what you're trying to do, nor shown any effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Nope sure didnt copy or paste anything! Just because you dont know the answer doesnt mean you should make that statement! I just dont know how to get the answer for n!

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct, your series in `Ap`.
  For series in `Ap` use formula sum of n `numbers=n*(a + l)/2;`
  here first term is a and last term is l.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int total = 0;
        int sumOfTotal = 0;
        int n = 0;


        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            total += i;
            sumOfTotal += total;
        }

           n=(sumOfTotal*2)/(a+l);
           System.out.println("value of n is"+ n);
        System.out.println(sumOfTotal);
    }
```

Comment: If you have read the post , I have mentioned here first term is a and last term is l . So you can declare them just as below.              a int a=1, int l=5; int sumOfTotal = 0;
int n = 0; thanks natwar